# mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, craft2, mamp

I have an old craft 2 installation.
When I want to go to the frontend I get:

> mkdir(): Permission denied

```
745     {
746         if ($permissions == null)
747         {
748             $permissions = craft()->config->get('defaultFolderPermissions');
749         }
750 
751         $path = static::normalizePathSeparators($path);
752 
753         if (!static::folderExists($path, false, $suppressErrors))
754         {
755             $oldumask = $suppressErrors ? @umask(0) : umask(0);
756 
757             if ($suppressErrors ? !@mkdir($path, $permissions, true) : !mkdir($path, $permissions, true))
758             {
759                 Craft::log('Tried to create a folder at '.$path.', but could not.', LogLevel::Error);
760                 return false;
761             }
762 
763             // Because setting permission with mkdir is a crapshoot.
764             $suppressErrors ? @chmod($path, $permissions) : chmod($path, $permissions);
765             $suppressErrors ? @umask($oldumask) : umask($oldumask);
766             return new Folder($path);
767         }
768 
769         Craft::log('Tried to create a folder at '.$path.', but the folder already exists.', LogLevel::Warning);
```

Where can I read out the folder which has no permission?
I've set recursive chmod 777 on all files in the project (yes I know).
But this doesn't change anything.

It is on a local MAMP Pro install. Nothing is showing in any logs.

But the Control Panel is working fine.

I also tried to change the user in mamp. As suggested on discord. But that does nothing.

‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I was in Craft 2, but I'd suggest checking out this page in the docs:

https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/folder-structure.html

Do all of the directories mentioned on that page exist on your site? Specifically, I'd confirm that you have the `craft/storage` folder created in your installation. If it's not there, make it and try to load the page again.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. It was the asset transformations.

If I change `'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,` to `false`
the site is being displayed (without images).

Changing asset permissions doesn't change anything.
But at least I can now view the site again.

Comment: One of your asset sources is probably misbehaving? Might be worth a trip to the asset settings and see what's up. Upload a file to one of them and see what error you get.